# TSQL -- Where Statements on Multiple columns in Update

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

My basic question has to do with updating multiple columns at once from specified values in my query. The reason I want to do this is that I am updating my values from a ginormous table so I only want to query it once in order to reduce run time.  Here is an example of an example select statement that returns the value I want for just one of the columns I need to update:

```
select a.Value
from Table1
left outer join
(
select ID, FilterCol1, FilterCol2, Value
from Table2
) a on a.ID = Table1.ID
where {Condition1a on FilterCol1}
and {Condition2a on FilterCol2}
```

In order to update multiple columns at once I would like to be able do something like this (but it returns NULL):

```
Update T1
set T1Value1 = (select a.Value where {Condition1a on FilterCol1}
and {Condition2a on FilterCol2)
,T1Value2 = (select a.Value where {Condition1b on FilterCol1}
and {Condition2b on FilterCol2})
from Table1 T1
left outer join
(
select ID, FilterCol1, FilterCol2, Value
from Table2
) a on a.ID = Table1.ID
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated, let me know if you have any questions or if I made any errors. Thanks!

EDIT: I think I have identified the problem, but I'm not sure of a solution yet. I think seeing the issue requires a little more context: The select from table 2 is actually an unpivot on a wide table. This means that when the `left outer join` is applied, there will be multiple rows for a given ID. What the case statement that Earl suggested seems to be doing (and I assume this is happening with the where clause as well) is comparing my Conditions to only the first row of the columns from a. Since my conditions are meant to help determine which of the rows from `a` is chosen, they will always evaluate false for the first row (I know this just from what I know about the data), hence my perpetual `NULL` values. Does anyone know of a workaround to look at the other rows in `a`?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1Value1 = CASE WHEN (FilterCol1 = Condition1a  AND FilterCol2 = Condition2a) THEN a.Value END,
    T1Value2 = CASE WHEN (FilterCol1 = Condition1b  AND FilterCol2 = Condition2b) THEN a.Value END

FROM Table1 T1
left outer join
        (
        select ID, FilterCol1, FilterCol2, Value
        ) a on a.ID = Table1.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Earl, unfortunately this did not work for me (still returned null). I'm wondering if this would actually filter what values are put into `T1ValueX` or filter which rows of `Table1` are updated. Does it make a difference that `FilterCol(1,2)` are columns from `Table2` but `Condition(1,2)(a,b,...)` are looking at values in `Table1`?

Comment: Can you add tables and sample data?

Comment: The WHERE clause will filter the rows updated. The CASE would select the value. It doesn't matter if you have linked the tables correctly what table the values are coming from. Linking tables is perhaps the most easily misunderstood aspects to people new to sql. I suggest in the future if you have questions, add a creation of a table(s) & test data.

Comment: Sorry Earl I forgot to look back at this because I found a work around! I ended up using `UNION ALL`s to create a wide data set with the values i wanted for each T1ValueX in column X. This actually made everything run extremely quickly because a lot of filtering was done in each `UNION ALL` so each select was fairly small. Thanks for your input!